# Php count tags in XML

Tags: php, xml

I am looking for how to count tags in an XML file.

This is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <contenu>
        <images>
            <image>1.jpg</image>
            <image>aid.jpg</image>
            <image>298jd.jpg</image>
        </images>
    </contenu>
    <contenu>
        <images>
            <image>112.jpg</image>
            <image>ai2d.jpg</image>
            <image>29228jd.jpg</image>
            <image>29zz8jd.jpg</image>
        </images>
    </contenu>
    <contenu>
        <images>
            <image>12.jpg</image>
        </images>
    </contenu>
```

I would view this :

```
images[0]=> 3 tags <image>
images[1]=> 4 tags <image>
images[2]=> 1 tags <image>
```

But I can not get anything.

Can you help me

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: That example isn't actually valid XML. Add a more realistic excerpt, and any prior failed attempts.

Comment: This is valid XML `<contenu>
    <images>
        <image>1.jpg</image>
        <image>aid.jpg</image>
        <image>298jd.jpg</image>
    </images>
</contenu>
<contenu>
    <images>
        <image>112.jpg</image>
        <image>ai2d.jpg</image>
        <image>29228jd.jpg</image>
        <image>29zz8jd.jpg</image>
    </images>
</contenu>
<contenu>
    <images>
        <image>12.jpg</image>
    </images>
</contenu>`

Comment: Sorry to say but this is not valid xml format. If you have any valid xml you can use counters to accomplish this task.... plase post more detaisl and valid example..

Comment: @user3245543 update your question with valid XML, instead of posting the XML in comment (hard to read). Also you still failed to show your attempt.

Comment: My question has update

Comment: You are missing PHP script in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The XML that you have provided is invalid. I have included a root_tag.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<root_tag>
    <contenu>
        <images>
            <image>1.jpg</image>
            <image>aid.jpg</image>
            <image>298jd.jpg</image>
        </images>
    </contenu>
    <contenu>
        <images>
            <image>112.jpg</image>
            <image>ai2d.jpg</image>
            <image>29228jd.jpg</image>
            <image>29zz8jd.jpg</image>
        </images>
    </contenu>
    <contenu>
        <images>
            <image>12.jpg</image>
        </images>
    </contenu>
</root_tag>
```

You could use this PHP script to get the output

```
<?php
    $xml=simplexml_load_file("test.xml");

    $var = $xml->contenu;
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($var as $value) {
        echo 'images['.$i.'] '.count($value->images->image).' tags &lt;'.$value->images->image->getName().'&gt;<br/>';
        $i++;
    }
?>
```